# How to put multiple layout themes on 'slide_layouts' on python-pptx

Tags: python, python-pptx

I've been trying to use some custom layouts on a python-pptx prs, but when I call the prs.slide_layouts method, it return only some of the layouts, only from one of the layout themes. The presentation I'm using has almost 100 layouts, but when I call the follow code, it prints 12 numbers (in order, from 1 to 11).

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt

for slide_layout in prs.slide_layouts:
    print(prs.slide_layouts.index(slide_layout))
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
```

How can I acess all layout themes on python-pptx? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each slide layout belongs to one-and-only-one slide master.

`prs.slide_layouts` is a handy shortcut for `prs.slide_masters[0].slide_layouts`; handy because most presentations only have the one slide-master.

If you have *multiple* slide masters, then you need to be explicit about which one you want to pull from. Maybe something like:

```
def iter_all_layouts(prs):
    """Generate each slide layout in the presentation, across all slide masters."""
    for master in prs.slide_masters:
        for layout in master.slide_layouts:
            yield layout
```

Or if you know you want the third layout of the second master:

```
prs.slide_masters[1].slide_layouts[2]
```

Comment: Worked out. Thank you! I've never worked on multiple slide-master presentations and I was really pissed by this. I've spent 2 hours thinking about. Now I can start using the python-pptx lib